# What does variable = !variable mean?

Tags: c#

I have this code. What does it mean?

```
bool q = false;

if (i < 0) {

    q = !q;

}
```

I assume `!q` means true?

**UPDATE:** The full code is below. When `!` is used in the IF statement, is the variable in that situation always false?

```
bool q = false;

if (i < 0) {

    q = !q;

}

if (!q) {

    /// do stuff
}
```

Comment: it is toggling the value

Comment: `!q` means the opposite of the current value of `q`.  So in your example, yes, `!q` is `true`, until the assignment, after which `q` is `true` and `!q` would be `false`.

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial - Variables and their types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm) I would suggest some remedial reading this is very simple to understand

Comment: How come you didn't set a breakpoint on `q = !q` to see what it was doing?

Comment: You should not be editing multiple questions into the question.  You should be asking one question per question.

Comment: because most people whom come to this site are always expecting a quick fix when in fact 9out of 10 times the answer(s) are sitting right there in front of their face.. why does every body want to be a `coder` but don't do what's necessary to become proficient in coding? respectfully speaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a boolean like here, the variable q can be either true or false.

when you put a ! in front of something in most languages, it means "opposite"

As example,

> `1 != 2`

means:

> 1 is opposite of equal to 2

.
This being for a condition, in your case, it would mean

> assign the opposite of q to q.

Also, I believe most people on SO (Stack Overflow) will tell you this question does not belong here because you can find it easily on the internet, if you want, there are various books to learn programming. You can search "it ebooks" on the internet and you will probably find many for free .

Comment: If you know that the question doesn't belong here, then why did you answer it?

Comment: No need for sarcasm or rudeness, some people dont necessarily know how to search for code explanations, since they can be hard to find directly on google.

Answer (score 5):

All it means is it's "not q", so it's opposite of whatever q is.

Comment: @user2217162 If q is false then not q must be not false.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, it switches the bool property from `true` to `false`.  In your example, `q` starts as `false`. If `i` is less than 0 then `q` becomes `true`.  Then comes the `if` statement, which says "if `q` is `false`, then execute the next code block".  `q` only stays false if `i` is greater than or equal to 0. So no, the code inside your if block will not always execute.  It depends on `i`.

Comment: thanks!! in the updated part of my code, is the IF statement always referring to a "false" variable?????

Comment: @user2217162 You can think of `if(!q)` as the same as `if(q == false)`.